# update database table on session timeout in php

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ajax, session-timeout

I have a php code as shown below in which session timeout happen after 60 mins when there is no activity. The following code is inside the file **/mno.php**. My **login and logout cod**e is also in the same file **/mno.php**.

**/mno.php**

```
if (isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) && (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] > 3600)) {
    session_destroy();   // destroy session data in storage
    !isset($_SESSION['pageadmin']);

    /* Update Table (START) */
    $open="false";
    $stmt= $connect->prepare("UPDATE trace_users SET open=? WHERE user_name=?");
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $open, $_SESSION['user_name']);
    $stmt->execute();
    /* Update Table (END) */

    header('location: /mmo.php');
    exit();
}
$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time(); // update last activity time stamp
```

The table **trace_users** in the code keeps the track of all logged in users. In that table, there are two columns **user_name** and **open**. The value is set to **true/false** when any user **log in/log out**.

I have included sql query in which I am trying to update a table when there is no activity but ***unfortunately the column value is not getting set to false for that particular user*** when no activity happens for 60 mins.

**This is what I have tried:**

After doing some research, I think I have to run a timer (js/ajax). In the javascript shown below I have calculated the difference between the **Last Activity** and the **Current time**. 
If its more than 60 mins, then it will update a db table.  This is what I have tried but I believe more need to be done in order to update a table in db.

```
<script>
let x = setInterval(function() {

    let lastActivity = <?php echo ($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']); ?>
    let now = <?php echo time() ?>;
    let difference = now - lastActivity;

    if (difference > 3600) {
        clearInterval(x);
    }
}, 1000
);
</script>
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the js (or php) code above so that when there is no activity for 60 mins, it should update the column **open** to **false** (in the table **trace_users**) for that particular user.

[image]

**Edit 1:**

My login code and session history code is in the same file **/mno.php**. I have placed everything in the same file **/mno.php**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you realize that this code

```
if (isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) && (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] > 3600)) {
    //...
}
$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time(); // update last activity time stamp
```

runs on every request and **only when a request arrives**

Imagine I visit your website and then go out shopping keeping the browser open. What do you think will happen?
NOTHING - because there will be no new request sent to you (assuming you haven't implemented any periodic ajax polling / Websocket mechanism)

So the server won't bother about me until I come back from shopping and refresh the page, only then would the server realize "Hmmm..This guy's LAST_ACTIVITY is older than an hour let me update my `trace_users` table and set open as `false` for him"

Coming to your proposed solution, it looks good and avoids the complications of websockets/periodic ajax requests

Just need some minor corrections, follow here for a basic demo

```
<script>

    var lastActivity = <?php echo ($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']); ?>; //the timestamp of latest page refresh or navigation 
                                                                    //This will remain constant as long as page stays put
    var now = <?php echo time() ?>; //This takes inital value (technically same as LAST_ACTIVITY) from server 
                                    // but later on it will be incremented by javascript to act as counter
    var logoutAfter = 5; //I set 5 sec for demo purposes

    var timer = setInterval(function() {
                    now++;
                    let delta = now - lastActivity;
                    if ( delta > logoutAfter) {
                        alert('you are logged out');
                        clearInterval(timer);
                        //DO AJAX REQUEST TO close.php
                    }
                }, 1000);

</script>
```

Here the `lastActivity` will hold the timestamp when the page was sent by server to browser it will be never changed by scripts on the browser, 
`now` is your counter that you will use to track how much time passed since page was loaded on the browser, you'll increment it every second and check if a given amount of time has been crossed

If true do a ajax request (or simply redirect to logout.php) where you would destroy session and update the `trace_users` table to mark the user as closed

**UPDATE**

So ajax will be like

```
$.ajax({      
    url: "/close.php", 
    type: 'POST', // GET also fine
    data: { },
    success: function(data) {
        window.location.href= '/mmo.php';
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus);
    }
});
```

and

> close.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$logoutAfter = 5; //5 sec timeout for testing purposes

// I'm not sure whether the below if condition check is required here or not 
// because we have already checked (whether to timeout or not ) in our javascript 
// and we call close.php only when it's affirmative
// I encourage you to test and find out :)

if (isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) && (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] > $logoutAfter)) {
    session_destroy();   // destroy session data in storage
    !isset($_SESSION['pageadmin']);

    /* Update Table (START) */
    $open="false";
    $stmt= $connect->prepare("UPDATE trace_users SET open=? WHERE user_name=?");
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $open, $_SESSION['user_name']);
    $stmt->execute();
    /* Update Table (END) */

    //header('location: /mmo.php'); //<-- no need of it when url hit by ajax
    exit();
}
else  //<-- note the else
$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time(); // update last activity time stamp
```

Comment: I checked your code and it looks good Viney thanks for the help. I am happy that my approach was right. Thanks for confirming that. According to your proposed solution when there is no activity for 5 seconds then the **(1)** page 
should log out automatically and bring the user to login.php (where I would destroy session) . **(2)** It should also update the table.

Comment: This is what I have tried https://jsfiddle.net/u68204ca/ I am wondering if you can have a look. In the fiddle, if you can let me know where I need to adjust the **update query** and the following 2 lines which is destroying session. 
`session_destroy();   // destroy session data in storage
!isset($_SESSION['pageadmin']);`

Comment: Thanks for the update. I checked your code and wanted to let you know something. My login code and session history code is in the same file **/mmo.php**. I have placed everything in the same php file **/mmo.php**. 
I have tried with this code http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a6aac316ad4a723db8fb2d217dfa437e19d9cbbc and its not working. I am getting the alert messages **you are logged out** and **error**

Comment: @user1950349 codesandbox is a limited environment you need to test on your local system. Use php's effortles inbuilt server `php -S localhost:8080`

Comment: Hi, I have shared the sandbox link to show which code I am using in my local system. It would be very messy to copy/paste the code in comments.

Comment: I've updated the code. Have a look at [page.php](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3283715ed8abaa1595422f9b40de2daa091cd0bd
) and [mmo.php](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/59831cd6fd346589f7e9ff0c2b417a4e51be8ab4)

Comment: page.php and mno.php they both are different ?

Comment: I checked your page.php and mno.php and I can't see much changes. I am wondering where did you make changes in the above 2 files ? Let me know.

Comment: Seems some issue with sandbox anyway I've posted in a new answer

Comment: I tested yoour code and everything is perfectly fine. The one thing which I noticed is that the page is getting log out even 
when there is an activity on the page. What does no activity actually means ?

Comment: It means any hit to the server whether it be through an AJAX or a simple page reload. That will update the `LAST_ACTIVITY` to "more amount" that will further extend the prospective logout.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. The other thing which I have noticed is when I am setting a session timeout for 60 mins (3600) then the db table was not getting updated 
but when I am setting a small session timeout lets say 60 seconds then the table gets updated after logout.

Comment: @user1950349 default session validity in php is 24 minutes, you need to increase it to atleast 61 minutes to have this code work. Check `session.gc_maxlifetime` in php.ini

Comment: So it means if I remove the all the session code then the page will logout automatically after 24 mins ?

Comment: No not like anything do with auto-logout it merely is a prerequisite in order for sessions to work properly [more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1270960)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know Viney. I just checked php.ini file and the following values are set  `session.gc_maxlifetime` **1440(Local Value)** **1440(Master Value)**

Comment: I am wondering why db table is not getting updated when I have setup the session timeout for 60 mins ? I also tried with 61 mins but still db table is not getting updated.

Comment: When I set something less than 60 seconds than the db table is getting updated.

Comment: Can you pls post all relevant code on github or something that supports separate files?

Comment: I have put my php code here https://3v4l.org/cNSil and JS code here 
https://jsfiddle.net/4t1psdo0/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212531/discussion-between-viney-and-user1950349).

Answer (score 2):

I think Vineys and jo0gbe4bstjbs answer is wrong because of when user close browser until 5 seconds, it can't update table after 60 mins and session too. Session deletes just after time in where set in php.ini configuration file. 
And Do you mind requesting every 5 seconds is it good way to solve this? It is worst for performance. 
If you want solve this problem with professionalism, you should add "last_request" column and delete "open" column from the table and after every request you should update last_requests value to current unix timestamp. And where getting users you should write:

```
$time = time() - 3600;

"SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE last_request > $time" //active users
"SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE last_request <= $time" //inactive users
```

And instead of ajax request every 5 seconds you should write setTimeout with 3600 second delay time which run window.location.href= '/mmo.php'; code.
Its way good if you want best performance and exactly result with 60 minute logout

Comment: Who told we are doing ajax EVERY 5 minutes?

Comment: I'm sorry you wrote 'demo purposes'. But check every 1000 milliseconds too bad for browser. I think you should do setTimeout(function() {
                        alert('you are logged out');
                        //DO AJAX REQUEST TO close.php
                    }
                }, 3600000);

Answer (score 0):

Page.php

```
<!-- CODE TO INCLUDE IN HEADER.PHP -->

<?php  
session_start();
$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time(); // update last activity time stamp  
?>



<!-- CLOSE -->

<html>

<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

</body>

<script>
let lastActivity = <?php echo ($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']); ?>; //the timestamp of latest page refresh or navigation
//This will remain constant as long as page stays put
let now = <?php echo time() ?>; //This takes inital value (technically same as LAST_ACTIVITY) from server+
                                // but later on it will be incremented by javascript to act as counter
let logoutAfter = 5; //I set 5 secs for demo purposes


let timer = setInterval(function() {
    now++;
    let delta = now - lastActivity;

    if ( delta > logoutAfter) {
        alert('you are logged out');
        clearInterval(timer);
        //DO AJAX REQUEST TO close.php
        $.ajax({
            url: "/mmo.php",
            type: 'POST', // GET also fine
            data: { },
            success: function(data) {

            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log("I am inside error");
                alert(textStatus);
            }
        });
    }
}, 1000); //<-- you can increse it( till <= logoutAfter ) for better performance as suggested by @"Space Coding"

</script>

</html>
```

mmo.php

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username   = "username";
$password   = "password";
$dbname     = "myDB";

$connect = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($connect->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $connect->connect_error);
}

session_start();
$logoutAfter = 5; //5 sec timeout for testing purposes

if (isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) && (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] > $logoutAfter)) {
    session_destroy();   // destroy session data in storage
    !isset($_SESSION['pageadmin']);

    /* Update Table (START) */
    $open="false";

    $stmt= $connect->prepare("UPDATE trace_users SET open=? WHERE user_name=?");
    $usname = !empty($_SESSION['user_name'])?$_SESSION['user_name']:'';

    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $open, $usname );
    $stmt->execute();
    /* Update Table (END) */

    //header('location: /mmo.php'); //<-- no need of it when url hit by ajax
    exit();
}
else  //<-- note the else
$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time(); // update last activity time stamp  
?>
```

Comment: I am getting an error at this line  `$stmt->bind_param('ss', $open, !empty($_SESSION['user_name'])?$_SESSION['user_name']:'' );`. It says that only variables can be passed by reference.

Comment: Can you check what `print_r($_SESSION['user_name'])` gives?

Comment: It prints the user who is currently logged in .

Comment: Is it array or string?

Comment: its a string (like this **david**)

Comment: Need to store $_SESSION['user_name'] in a variable $usname to use in prepare function

Comment: i am testing, stay tuned.

Answer (score -1):

This is a simple time validation for web page:

```
$modified_on = isset($SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']) ? $SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'] : null;

$current_time = time();

if (!is_null($modified_on) && ($current_time - strtotime($modified_on)) > 3600) {
    session_destroy();
    ...
}

header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', $current_time).' GMT');

...
```

Comment: That is a request header, sent by browser.